# How can I set one directional relation between two tables in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

For all classes in my Entity I have  a base class named CommonFields

```
public class CommonFields
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int CreaedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And, for eg. I have two classes like

```
public class Employee : CommonFields
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

public class User : CommonFields
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}
```

How can I set relation from CreatedBy & ModifiedBy to User table. I just need only one directional mapping (I don't want FK to be created in my User Table).

I need to get User information when I write objEmployee.CreatedUser

Thanks.

Comment: first, what did you try ? second, it will depend on you choice between TablePerType or TablePerinHeritance ?